# How to revert words that contain repeated letters to their original English form?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

Currently, I am working on project "Twitter Sentimental Analysis". I came across a problem where I need to revert words containing repeated letters. For example, "coooooool" to be replaced by "cool". I thought of using regex, but the words to be reverted are more in count. Can you please help me by providing a way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for libraries like `pyenchant` but for what exactly you are asking for, here is a code snippet. It won't do exactly what you are trying to do but it will convert all multiple occurrences of characters to single. then you could have a dictionary to replace/ignore right kind of words.

```
clean_words=[]    
for w in words:
    w = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)', '', w)
    clean_words.append(w)
```

As I mentioned while `looooove` becomes `love`, it will also make `cool` to `col`. For words like cool you will need look-up or dictionary to ignore the processing.